# What is the syntax to checkout a tagged release from SVN with bower?

Tags: svn, bower

The following command works:

```
svn co http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9 foobar
```

When I try and use bower to fetch the same code I put the following int the `dependencies` section of my `bower.json`:

```
"infobox": "svn+http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9"
```

Bower fails with:

```
bower infobox#*             not-cached svn+http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9#*
bower infobox#*                resolve svn+http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9#*
bower infobox#*                ECMDERR Failed to execute "svn list http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/tags --verbose", exit code of #1
```

Bower appends `/tags` to the path it passes to `svn list`. How do I make bower use the exact path I specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I could do for now is to install the entire infobox tag folder, so you would have to pick the 1.1.9/ folder inside there.

```
    "infobox": "svn+http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn#infobox"
```

I'm almost sure that Bower does not support nested tag folders like these, as the entire project is based on Git that has a more strict logic for tags.

Hope this helps,